# Can I use Glassfish open sources version commercially?

Tags: licensing, glassfish

I was wondering if I need to have a license for Glassfish open sources to use it commercially? For example, like write software that run on Glassfish, and this software is not free.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you may!

> This is the first, commercially supported, Java EE 6compatible
>   application server in the industry.
>   http://fixunix.com/solaris-rss/570434-top-10-reasons-not-using-glassfish-v3.html
>
> Bartek asks Is GlassFish for Commercial Use? The answer is YES; no
>   ifs, buts or any qualifiers. The license allows it, the code is
>   production quality, there is commercial support for it...
>   http://blogs.oracle.com/theaquarium/entry/glassfish_for_commercial_use

[Sun To Provide Commercial Support for Glassfish](http://www.internetnews.com/dev-news/article.php/3666281/Sun+To+Provide+Commercial+Support+for+Glassfish.htm)

[Glassfish Dual License CDDL&GPL](http://glassfish.java.net/public/CDDL+GPL.html)

Answer (score 4):

GlassFish Server Open Source Edition is dual-licensed under the GPLv2 with ClassPath Exception and the CDDL.  This means that you can use the open source binaries in production. You can download this from glassfish.org

Here is a link to the licenses:
http://glassfish.java.net/public/CDDL+GPL_1_1.html

On the other hand, Oracle GlassFish Server is available under a commercial license and includes support, patches, and some additional features.  You can download this from oracle.com/goto/glassfish.